# Array index out of bounds in sieve of eratosthenes

Tags: arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having trouble with ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. 
I am new to coding and I don't fully understand this problem and I am unable to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Primes {

public static void main(String[] args) {

final int SIZE = 10000;
        boolean[] numberIsPrime = new  boolean[SIZE];
        int rowCounter = 0;

        for( int index = 1; index <= SIZE; index++) {

            numberIsPrime[index] = true;
        }

        for( int index = 2; index <= SIZE; index++) {

            if( numberIsPrime[index] = true){

            for( int i = index; i <= SIZE; i++){

                numberIsPrime[index * i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    for( int index = 1; index <= SIZE; index++){
        if( numberIsPrime[index] = true){   
            System.out.println(index + "  ");
            rowCounter++;
            if( rowCounter == 10){
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }   
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should tag the question with the language you're using, but I'm gonna assume it's Java. The problem is

```
    boolean[] numberIsPrime = new  boolean[SIZE];
    ...
    for( int index = 1; index <= SIZE; index++) {

        numberIsPrime[index] = true;
    }
```

The first line declares numberIsPrime as an array of size 10000. That means you can access `numberIsPrime[0], numberIsPrime[1], ... numberIsPrime[9999]`. You can't access `numberIsPrime[10000]`.